# Is it possible to transmutate hydrogen into the chemicals and fuse them to create bread?

Tags: chemistry

I was wondering whether it would be chemically possible to take hydrogen from the air and transmute it into the required elements used to make bread. It doesn't have to be bread, it could be any food or even the crops to make bread. I was just wondering whether it could be possible to do this to end world hunger.

Comment: I think the process you are asking about is [Nuclear Transmutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_transmutation), paired with an ability to assemble food items from raw elements?

Comment: I suppose you could fire enough protons and neutrons to transmute hydrogen and oxygen into nitrogen and carbon...but *why*? We have oodles of nitrogen and carbon already. Using this process, you could perhaps make a dough for (phenomenally expensive) unleavened bread....but you could not make the yeast nor do the baking. The particle beams needed to do the transmutation aren't cheap, you know.  Much cheaper (and safer) to use *soil* to assemble the elements from the environment.

Comment: You put a "chemistry" tag on this. That's not appropriate since you can't change the chemical elements from inside chemistry. So you can't change hydrogen into other elements within the bounds of your question.

Comment: Also, are you thinking about what plants do? They essentially "make bread" from air, plus water (provided by rain, which also comes from air) and sunlight.

Comment: What "hydrogen from the air"? For all practical purposes there is no hydrogen in the air. *And in addition* you cannot transmute anything within chemistry; you need nuclear physics for transmutation.

Comment: The answer is yes, and you'll need to use your hydrogen and a load of other useful things to make a star, and hope that its protoplanetary disc produces a nice terrestrial planet in its habitable zone, and that life forms on that planet, and one of those life forms is a nice grassy thing with carb-rich seeds, and that intelligent naked monkeys will appear and crush it into dust and set it on fire and eat the result. Easy as that.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: No, I don't. But then I had typed my comment, which I have now deleted.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: I could certainly use some hydrogen...

Comment: @AlexP duly noted ;-)

Comment: @AlexP, there is water in the air. At least most of the time. By atoms, two thirds hydrogen and one third oxygen.

Comment: I want to repeat what Alexp already said: that's not what air is made out of. Don't say water, we have better sources for water than the air. However, technically that's what plants do: they take carbon!!!! from the air and that's ultimately what bread is made from: air. Air + dirt + water + sunlight. Sounds expensive to you? All 3 are basically free. Maybe world hunger has other causes than a shortage of the basic compounds for bread

Comment: You say "*do this to end world hunger*".  Despite what the do-gooders would have us believe, the vast majority of famines are not caused by a lack of food.  They almost all have political causes.  Sometimes it's through ignorant mismanagement (e.g. China), and sometimes it's deliberate (e.g. Russia's starvation of Ukraine).  This: [Famine: The Black Horseman Is Not Finished Riding | theTrumpet.com](https://www.thetrumpet.com/17854-famine-the-black-horseman-is-not-finished-riding) ends with a religious message, but the first part of the article is quite factual.

Answer (score 5):

On this site we answer questions about building (more or less consistent) fictional worlds. So the answer is **in principle yes, in practice no**. What you describe is slightly more realistic than the replicator in Star Trek.

With any realistic technology, transmuting **enough** hydrogen atoms to make even a single grain of wheat will be impractical unless your gadget is literally the size of a star, and if one had the proper elements fully synthetic creation of something as complex as bread would still be beyond present-day technology.

As a slightly more realistic option, all the elements which go into sugar or starch are present in the atmosphere, and filtering them out would be more practical than transmuting hydrogen. You would still be left with the job of synthesizing organic molecules, which is possible but difficult. The result would be some sort of bland [gruel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruel), not proper bread.

Ending world hunger is currently a question of **distribution**, not of **quantity**.

- People in many parts of the world are chronically overfed. Elsewhere people are starving because they *cannot afford* to pay for food that could easily be imported.
- The amount of food that is wasted during production and transport is staggering, just to assure that wealthy buyers get good-looking fruit 365 days a year and that supermarket shelves are full until closing time. At the end of the day or the week, unsold food goes into dumpsters.
- Farmers in many parts of the world grow fodder for animals, which is less efficient than growing cereals and vegetables for human consumption with just enough meat for a balanced diet.

Answer (score 3):

I think o.m.'s answer is fantastic, but I just wanted to observe one little fact: the energy that we harvest from nuclear fission reactors comes from *somewhere*.  It isn't magic.  When you start with hydrogen and create heavier elements, you are doing fusion, which is the opposite of fission.  And that means that the energy released during fission *came from fusion*.  Now, we can't fission elements down to hydrogen, because they are too stable.  In fact, most of the binding energy inside elementary nuclei is not available to us for consumption.  But it all got put into elementary hydrogen by *someone*, *somewhere*, and that "someone" was generally a supernova (dying star).

So given that we currently power a decent portion of our society by *breaking apart* elements, you can begin to imagine the power cost of assembling those elements from scratch.  As o.m. observes, it literally takes the power of a star, and a violently exploding one to get anything heavier than iron.  A nuclear power plant runs on a surprisingly small mass of radionuclides.  Current reactors produce on the order of 1,250 GJ/kg of enriched uranium.  Which means that if we could run the reaction backwards and perfectly, we would need to supply 1,250 GJ to turn a kg of strontium back into uranium.

Now, uranium is much heavier than the elements in food, so this is not an apples-to-apples comparison, but strontium itself has a high internal binding energy, so I would guess that the order of magnitude isn't that far off from H->Ca.  A kg of bread is about 2.5 loaves.  Also, a kg provides roughly enough calories to feed a single person for a day.  A GWe nuclear power plant consumes about 25 tonnes of enriched uranium per year.  If we could instead perfectly transmute a kg of enriched uranium into a kg of bread, your billion dollar nuclear power plant could feed a grand total of less than 70 people per year.  It costs about 140 million USD/year to fuel and operate such a plant, so you're feeding those people at the bargain basement price of about $2 million/person.

Needless to say, if you can afford to spend $2 million/person on food, you're better off building greenhouses. ;)